# Terminal Services command "Query Session" in C#

Tags: c#, terminal-services

I'm looking to retrieve this information using C#.  I know that I can Shell out and execute these commands, but I'm hoping that I can do it all through System.Diagnostic namespace... 
[image]

Comment: Enumerate processes and p/invoke WTSQuerySessionInformation with each Process.SessionId for the name, filter as needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cassia](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cassia/) did the trick for me...

From the link listed above, and thans to Alex K for pointing me in the right direction, I just didn't was to do any p/invoke without a covering library.

Cassia supports the following operations on both local and remote terminal servers: * Enumerating terminal sessions and reporting session information including connection state, user name, client name, client display details, client-reported IP address, and client build number (WTSEnumerateSessions, WTSQuerySessionInformation, and friends) * Logging off a session (WTSLogoffSession) * Disconnecting a session (WTSDisconnectSession) * Displaying a message box in a session and getting a response from the user (WTSSendMessage) * Enumerating all processes (WTSEnumerateProcesses) * Killing a process (WTSTerminateProcess) * Shutting down or rebooting the server (WTSShutdownSystem) In addition, Cassia supports enumerating all terminal servers on a domain (WTSEnumerateServers).